# Nested foreach only goes through all loops

Tags: php, foreach, nested

Can anyone tell me why my foreach loops only loop one time through. The outer loop runs and then the two inner loops. After that it stops.

```
function saarealty_get_mls()
{
    $property_classes = ['RESI', 'COMM', 'VACANTLAND', 'MULT'];

    // generate the DMQL query  
    $query = "(Status=|ACTV,SOLD),(IDXOptInYN=1)";

    foreach ($property_classes as $pc) {

        $Photos = [];

        // make the request and get the results    
        $results = $rets->Search('Property', $pc, $query);

        // save the results in a local file     
        file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/Property_' . $pc . '.json', $results->toJSON());

        foreach ($results as $r) {
            $photos  = [];
            $sysid   = $r['Matrix_Unique_ID'];
            $objects = $rets->GetObject('Property', 'LargePhoto', $sysid, '*', 1);

            foreach ($objects as $object) {
                $photos[] = $object->getLocation();
            }

            foreach ($photos as $p) {
                $Photos[] = $p;
            }
            $photos_json = json_encode($Photos);
            file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/Photos_' . $pc . '.txt', $photos_json);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance,

Comment: this code is really bad. so many nested loops is a smell itself but apart from that. where is stuff coming from like `$rets`. what happens when `$r` does not contain `Matrix_Unique_ID`. does `$rets->GetObject` always return an array...and so on. Please refactor, use a debugger and error reporting. You'll most likely solve your problem on the way.

Comment: which loop stops please mention loop.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.   @HidayatUllah It quits after the second inner loop runs.  Both file write once and they should both write 4 times.  Stuff iis coming a multi listing service

Comment: You mean the most outer loop execute only once?

Comment: @Hidayat Ullah yes the most outer loop.  Thanks.